# Revit (bim) and javascript/python

Tags: javascript, model, revit

Can I update a Revit model using JavaScript or python? How can I view the model on a web browser?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Autodesk Forge. It's a web based technology for converting Revit files to something that can be viewed in the browser.

https://forge.autodesk.com/

There are also free and open source libraries that you could try like the one from TT-Core called Spectacles:

http://core.thorntontomasetti.com/apps/Spectacles/#secondPage